# Collapsible graphviz alternative for nested nodes

Tags: graphviz

I am working on a hobby project and I need an alternative for graphviz to show nested nodes with collapsible features. For example , 
[image]

I need this to be in a form

[image]

So that when I click on a0 it gives me the original diagram.